# Retrieving Medium or Large Profile Image from Twitter with omniauth-twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using omniauth-twitter gem to authenticate users through twitter.  I am also using their Twitter profile image as their avatar for my site.  However, the image I get from Twitter is low resolution.  I know Twitter has better resolution pics available.  How do I get it?

Here is what I am currently doing.  It is a method in the user model.  It works, just doesn't get me a good quality pic:

user.rb

```
  def update_picture(omniauth)
    self.picture   = omniauth['info']['image'] 
  end
```

I thought maybe I could pass a size option onto it somehow, but can not seem to find a good solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm using the omniauth-twitter gem as well.  In the apply_omniauth method of my User model, I save the Twitter image path like this, stripping the **_normal** suffix:

```
if omniauth['provider'] == 'twitter'
    self.image = omniauth['info']['image'].sub("_normal", "")
end
```

Then I have a helper method called portrait that accepts a size argument.  As Terence Eden suggests, you can just replace the **_size** suffix of the filename to access [the different image sizes that Twitter provides](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/:screen_name):

```
def portrait(size)

    # Twitter
    # mini (24x24)                                                                  
    # normal (48x48)                                            
    # bigger (73x73)                                                
    # original (variable width x variable height)

    if self.image.include? "twimg"

        # determine filetype        
        case 
        when self.image.downcase.include?(".jpeg")
            filetype = ".jpeg"
        when self.image.downcase.include?(".jpg")
            filetype = ".jpg"
        when self.image.downcase.include?(".gif")
            filetype = ".gif"
        when self.image.downcase.include?(".png")
            filetype = ".png"
        else
            raise "Unable to read filetype of Twitter image for User ##{self.id}"
        end

        # return requested size
        if size == "original"
            return self.image
        else
            return self.image.gsub(filetype, "_#{size}#{filetype}")
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: This answer gives a more detailed and useful answer, along with the solution for removing the "_normal" with the sub method. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Once you have the URL of the image, it's quite simple. You need to remove the "_normal" from the end of the URL.

Here's my avatar image

```
https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2318692719/7182974111_ec8e1fb46f_s_normal.jpg
```

Here's the larger version

```
https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2318692719/7182974111_ec8e1fb46f_s.jpg
```

A simple regex should suffice.

Remember, the size of the image is unpredictable - so you may wish to resize it before displaying it on your site.

Comment: you lost me at "A simple regex"  :)  I'll try it out.  Any recommendations on how best to add the regex to the method I have? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, instead of saving the url with the modifications, I decided to modify the url when loading the image into the view with the .sub method like so:  user.picture.sub("normal", "reasonably_small")

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this is through the config options of the `omniauth-twitter` gem.

`provider :twitter, "API_KEY", "API_SECRET", :image_size => 'original'`

https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter