# Get the Twitter profile picture url using JQuery

Tags: url, jquery, twitter, syntax-error, image

I would like to simply retrieve the url of a Twitter profile picture using JQuery

for that I use :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/twitterapi.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('error');
    }
```

});

But I get this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Anyone knows where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Try to open that URL in the browser. You will get "redirected" to some other URL. Verify that via `curl -v` and check for `Location: ...` header.

---

The solution would be to request JSONP from the url:

[`https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true&callback=foo`](https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=TwitterAPI&include_entities=true)

You will get the image URL from `profile_image_url` field of the root object.

Comment: Yes but I actually want to also get the picture in original size and the /show.json does not provide original size

Comment: how can I check the location header in JQuery $.ajax ?

Comment: This is how you get the full sized image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426253/retreiving-medium-or-large-profile-image-from-twitter-with-omniauth-twitter

Comment: @kschaeffler: `var obj = $.ajax({..}); var headers = obj.getAllResponseHeaders();`

Answer (score 1):

This is a static URL and can get the latest twitter profile image url.

```
 https://twitter.com/{{#twitterUserName}}/profile_image?size=normal
```

My twitter userScreen name is rkramakrishna17

```
https://twitter.com/rkramakrishna17/profile_image?size=normal
```

**Edit 1:**

As Suggested by @juanmirocks we can get original Image by adding ?size=origianl to get original image.

```
https://twitter.com/{{#twitterUserName}}/profile_image?size=original
```

Comment: Just what I needed. You can also set the size to `original`